# Stripe Address Element: how to get the value of the Name field?

Tags: stripe-payments

The `address` is missing the name related values even when the `addressElement` is rendering the Name field even when using the same code as mentioned in the Stripe documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/address-element/collect-addresses?platform=web#web-retrieve-address)

```
addressElement.on('change', (event) => {
  if (event.complete){
    // Extract potentially complete address
    const address = event.value.address;
  }
})
```

returns this

```
{
    "line1": "",
    "line2": null,
    "city": "",
    "country": "US",
    "postal_code": "",
    "state": ""
}
```

It seems that the workaround to get the value could look like

```
document.getElementById('Field-nameInput').value
```

But doesn't look graceful.

Where is the value of the Name field? How do I get it? Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is available as `value.name` in the change event, or `firstName` and `lastName` if you use the `split` display for name. From the docs for `value` ([reference](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_change?type=addressElement#element_on_change-handler-value)):

> An object containing the current address information. The `firstName`
> and `lastName` properties only appear if the `display.name` option is set
> to split. The `phone` property only appears if the `fields.phone` option
> is set to `always`.

Comment: Thank you... it was right in the front and I couldn't see.